# Can we get the From email address that is set in MFMailComposeViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, mfmailcomposer

I am able to get Recipient email address from the MFMailComposeViewController using http://jomnius.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-find-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller.html  link.

But I want From email Address. So is their any way to get From email Address...

Any links related to this is also welcome...

thanks..

Comment: hi you find it`s solution then share here... cause u didn`t accept answer hope you get it... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to fetch User's Configured email address in iPhone. If so, You can't fetch email configuration of iOS devices due to privacy issues.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008200-CH1-DontLinkElementID_1

Comment: also check the instance method section. You'll find only setter methods.

Comment: Also check the link you have provided. At comment section second comment.